# How can I push one div in the footer section to the right?

Tags: html, css

```css
.top_navbar_items{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 15px;

}

.top_navbar_items a{
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.google_logo{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 150px;
 width: 585px;
}

#search_icon{
 background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/751/751463.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.search_box{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.search_btns{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
p{
 text-align: center;
}


footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
display:flex;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
background-color:rgba(240,240,240);
}


li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin:5px;
}


a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.fbar_right{
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Google</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_content">
    <nav class="top_navbar">
        <ul class="top_navbar_items">
            <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="google_logo">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </div>
    <div class="search_form">
        <div class="search_box">
            <div id="search_icon"></div>
            <input type="text" name="search_bar">
        </div>  
        <div class="search_btns">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Search" name="Google Search">
            <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="I'm Feeling Lucky">
        </div>      
    </div>
    <p>
        Google offered in: <a href="#">English</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <ul class="fbar_left">
            <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How Search works</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="fbar_right">
            <li><a href="#" class="test">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to push Provacy Terms Settings to the right bottom of the screen but I could not get it to work! I tried to put them into flexbox and try to change the flow but that does not move the them at all.

Also is there any other way to put footer adjacent to bottom of the page other than 
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You have to add only one line of code to your `css` file :-

```
  justify-content: space-between;
```

your `footer` element `css` will be :-

```
footer
{
  position          :  absolute;
  bottom            :  0;
  display           :  flex;
  justify-content   :  space-between;
  width             :  100%;
  margin            :  auto;
  background-color  :  rgba(240,240,240);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [justify-content](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) on the footer.

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it is weird that I found a solution after I ask a question although I have been searching it for 30 minutes!

So i set .fbar_right{position: absolute;
right:20px;}

And it moved it to the right! Thank you

Comment: use the css positioning properties when you absolutely want to most of the time you do not need them as in your case it does not need css positioning as it can be done simply using floats.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it using the code you have written would be:-

```
footer{
display:flex;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
background-color:rgba(240,240,240);
}

.fbar_left{
    width: 50%;
}

.fbar_right{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Or just do:-

```
footer{
display:flex;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
background-color:rgba(240,240,240);
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add anything else If i go with second option? Because when I copy and paste it, it does not appear at the bottom of the page so I have to use bottom: 0; again to make it go down.

Comment: https://codepen.io/akshaybhat301094/pen/PoPWMeM here check this like i have made it on codepen. You do not need to add anything else

Comment: I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding